# IllegalAccessExcepcion en pruebas parametrizadas con JUnit

Tags: java, pruebas-unitarias, junit-5

Estoy realizando un pequeño ejemplo de pruebas parametrizadas en ***eclipse*** usando ***JUnit***, resulta que al ejecutar las pruebas me aparece la siguiente excepción:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1 can not access a member of
>   class calculadora.EjemploParametrizacionTest with modifiers ""

los resultados aparecen así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las pruebas son para practica tomando el clasiso ejemplo de una calculadora, aqui esta el codigo de la clase de las pruebas:

```
package calculadora;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;


//utilizaremos la libreria que nos permite parametrizar nuestros Tests
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class EjemploParametrizacionTest extends CoreMatchers {




    //Creamos la lista de grupos de parametros de entrada para las pruebas
    static Iterable<Object[]> getData(){
         return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {3, 2, 5}, {2, 2, 4}, {5, 3, 8}, {5, 5, 10}
        });
    }


    /*utilizaremos las notaciones para recrear el uso de la suma en la calculadora,
     * usaremos un acumulador que sume todos los resultados durante las pruebas*/


    int total; //aqui guardaremos el acumulado de las operaciones
    Calculadora calc; //declaramos un objeto de tipo: calculadora 

    //Instanciamos la calculadora
    @BeforeAll
    void InstanciarCalculadora() {
        calc = new Calculadora();
    }

    //Con este metodo limpiaremos el resultado de la calculadora antes de cada @Test
    @BeforeEach
    void LimpiarResultado() {
        calc.Clear();
    }

    //Pruebas TestSumar(), TestSumar1()
    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getData")
    void testSumar(int a, int b, int exp) {
        //esta es la forma de hacer la asercion sin matchers de hamcrest
        //assertEquals("Error", exp, calc.Sumar(a, b)); 

        //forma con matchers de hamcrest (Mas entendible)
        assertThat("Error, no es el resutado esperado", calc.Sumar(a, b), equalTo(exp)); 

        //acumulado de este Test debe ser: 5+4+8+10=27
    }

    //tambien podemos pasar los parametros directamente a un Test así:
    @Test
    @Parameters({"2, 2, 4", "3, 3, 6", "4, 4, 8", "5, 5, 10"})
    void testSumar1(int a, int b, int exp) {
        assertThat("Error, no es el resultado esperado", calc.Sumar(a, b), equalTo(exp));
        //acumulado de este Test debe ser: 4+6+8+10=28
    }

    //Incrementamos el valor del resultado luego de cada @Test para llevar el acumulado
    @AfterEach
    void ContarAcumulado() {
        total += calc.getAcumulado();
        System.out.println("acumulado parcial: " + total);
    }

    //mostramos el acumulado de todas las operaciones una vez terminados todos los @Tests
    @AfterAll
    void MostrarTotal() {
        System.out.println("El acumulado total de las pruebas es: " + total);
    }
```

y la clase Calculadora:

```
package calculadora;

public class Calculadora {

    private int answer;
    private int acumulado;

    //Constructor
    Calculadora(){
        answer = 0;
        acumulado = 0;
    }

    //creamos 2 metodos uno para sumar y otro para restar
    //en JUnit5 ya no es necesario usar public en los metodos
    int Sumar(int a, int b) {
        answer = a + b;
        acumulado += answer;
        return answer;
    }

    int Restar(int a, int b) {
        answer = a - b;
        return answer;
    }

    /*creamos sobrecarga para los metodos Sumar() y Restar() para un solo parametro
     *  es decir que al pasarle un parametro, este se sume o se reste al valor actual 
     *  que tenga el atributo: answer*/
    int Sumar(int valor) {
        answer += valor;
        return answer;
    }

    int Restar(int valor) {
        answer -= valor;
        return answer;
    }

    //metodo para limpiar o reiniciar el valor de: answer
    void Clear() {
        answer = 0;
    }

    //creamos un getter para obtener el valor del atributo answer
    int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    int getAcumulado() {
        return acumulado;
    }
}
```

agradezco me pueden indicar cual seria el problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si pones los tests como públicos?

Comment: ya lo intente amigo y sigue lo mismo, el hecho de que no estén indicados los tipos de acceso public es porque no es necesario usarlos en JUnit5 ya la clase de pruebas solamente sera utilizada por JUnit. de igual forma muchas gracias por la sugerencia.